# DevTools memory tab has no profile tab

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

The [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory#profile-tab) says there should be a Profile tab inside the Memory tab, but it's missing from both the VSCode version and Chrome browser version. No Diff or Trace tab either. This is a iOS app running in profile mode. What can I do to make it show?[image]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-CA) 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1) 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0) 
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web 
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1) [✓] VS Code (version 1.74.0)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    
    • No issues found!
```